# Automatically generating natural Equals and GetHashCode functions for objects

Tags: c#

I have found myself overriding the *Equals* and *GetHashCode* functions quite often when making classes. It seems like a waste of time since most of the time my *Equals* is just checking for the equality of every member (or iterating to check equality of IEnumerable elements). Similarly my *GetHashCode* is usually just the standard list of `hash = hash * <prime> + <sub-hash>`, possibly iterated.

Is there a library to generate such natural Equals and GetHashCode functions? It seems possible using some of the meta-programming features of C#.

Comment: You could use resharper: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Generation__Equality_Members.html

Comment: FYI: If you use the [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) type, these members are synthesized for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 can generate these members for you.

To do that, right-click the class name and select `Quick actions and refactorings...` and then select `Generate Equals and GetHashCode`.

This displays a dialog where you choose the members that you want to contribute to the Equals and GetHashCode.

For example, given this class:

```
public sealed class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(int x, string y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; }
    public string Y { get; }
}
```

It will generate:

```
public sealed class TestClass : IEquatable<TestClass?>
{
    public TestClass(int x, string y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; }
    public string Y { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as TestClass);
    }

    public bool Equals(TestClass? other)
    {
        return other != null &&
               X == other.X &&
               Y == other.Y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(X, Y);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(TestClass? left, TestClass? right)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<TestClass>.Default.Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(TestClass? left, TestClass? right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}
```

It's worth pointing out that for the sample class above, you can actually achieve the same result by using a [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) like so:

```
public sealed record TestClass(int X, string Y);
```

This will generate a `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` using the `X` and `Y` properties of the record.

Given the `record` above, the following code:

```
TestClass t1 = new TestClass(1, "1");
TestClass t2 = new TestClass(1, "1");

Console.WriteLine(t1.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(t2.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(t1 == t2);
```

Outputs (on my computer):

```
-1671517974
-1671517974
True
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful! Sadly record types don't compare enumerable members by value, and similarly for the generated code, but it's a good starting point!

Comment: @gabrieliussla Yes, it wouldn't be safe to generate code to compare IEnumerables because they could be infinite in size (and also in general it's not safe to enumerate enumerables multiple times)